# Very simple ng-model watch not working

Tags: angularjs

Here is the jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/CLcfC/

code

```
var app = angular.module('app',['']);

app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'Change Me';
    $scope.$watch('text',function(){
        alert('Changed !');
    });


})
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model='text'/>
     <span>{{text}}</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I am not able to see the change in `$scope.text`. Please help.
This is so easy but what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript file loads after the AngularJS initialization and that's why it fails to find your module. In order to fix it change the initialization to a manual initialization.

First change your HTML and remove the `ng-app` directive:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="appRoot">
 <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model='text'/>
     <span>{{text}}</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Then go to your JavaScript and use [angular.bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap) method to manually attach your module:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'Change Me';
    $scope.$watch('text',function(){
        alert('Changed !');
    });
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('appRoot'), ['app']);
});
```

You can find more help on manual AngularJS initialization [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Comment: Thanks. I never had to use the `angular.boostrap` before though.

Answer (score 6):

Change the module creation to this, make sure you don't put a empty string in the `[]`. (Obvious the empty string is not a module that can be injected.)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MWa66/

Comment: Thanks. Very obvious mistake from my end.

Comment: Even though avladov is correct, you don't need to do a manual bootstrap.  @zsong answer should be preferred over avladov.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I solved this annoying thing!
The solution that worked for me was that I use angular UI router and there I had used the following code

```
.state('app.monimes', {
      url: "/monimes",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/monimes.html",
          controller: 'sampleCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

so then in the controller I had

/***
 * 
 *Controller for tests..
 */

```
.controller('sampleCtrl',['$scope','sampleService', function($scope, $sampleService) {


     $scope.username="em";
       // Watch for changes on the username property.
// If there is a change, run the function

    $scope.$watch('username', function(newUsername) {
        // uses the $http service to call the GitHub API
        // //log it 
        $scope.log(newUsername);
        // and returns the resulting promise
            $sampleService.events(newUsername)
                  .success(function(data, status, headers) {
                              // the success function wraps the response in data
                              // so we need to call data.data to fetch the raw data
                     $scope.events = data.data;
                  });
    },true);
}
]);
```

and in the view  I had

```
<div>
     <label for="username">Type in a GitHub username</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter a GitHub username, like a user" />
      <pre ng-show="username">{{ events }}</pre>
</div>
```

but that didn't work.

so I added `ng-controller="sampleCtrl"`
to the div and now it works :D

so that means that the view is loaded after the controller loads and the watcher doesn't get added to the watching variable.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm also using UI-Router / Ionic and running into this. I'm watching a string that is used in multiple `ng-models` but nothing fires except on initialization. Post back if you find more ways to overcome this, please.

Comment: You can use `ng-change` with `ui-router` which also explains the intent a bit more clearly.